# im trying to fetch available urls in webpage but the output is like plain text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
 
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    urls = link.get('href')
    print(urls)
```

the  URL to be printed as "https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/china-population/"

but is just printed as "world-population/china-population"

followed by I need to fetch one particular table from each URL fetched

Answer (score 1):

That's relative url so you have to make them absolute urls as follows

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
 
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    urls = link.get('href')
    full_url='https://www.worldometers.info'+urls
print(full_url)
```

Comment: thanks its worked, how do get one particular table from each URL , how can fetch from all the URLs at a time